# Improving performance - find the maximum number equal to its appearances within array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I was doing this test yesterday for a job, and though my code got 100% accurate it got 25% efficiency. I was wondering (not just to de better on this tests, but to code better), how could I make this code better. I'm guessing it has to do with using splice or unset instead of a for?

The excercise was: 
Given an array of intergers bigger than 0 I should return the maximum number where the number is equal to the amount of the number itself.
Example: [2, 3, 2, 5, 7] 2 appears 2 times so func should return 2.
Example: [2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3] 2 appears to times and, 3 appears 3 times, but since 3 is bigger, 3 is the expected answer.

```
function exercise(A){
        // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
        let result = 0;
        let amount;
        let prevNumbers = [];
        let continueLoop;

        for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++){

            amount = 1;

            //Check if number can be an actual result (means that it should be bigger than previous results)
            if(A[i] <= result){ continue; }

            //Check if number was looped before, if it was, continue with next number
            continueLoop = false;
            for( let ix = 0; ix < prevNumbers.length; ix++){
                if(prevNumbers[ix] ==  A[i]){
                    continueLoop = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(continueLoop){ continue; }

            //Check amount of times number appears in array
            for (let ix = i+1; ix < A.length; ix++){
                if(A[i] == A[ix]){
                    amount++;
                }    
            }
            //Check if amount appears equal times to number
            if(A[i] = amount){
                result = amount;
            }
            prevNumbers.push(A[i]);
        }
        return result;
}
```

Comment: You should probably write a single loop that counts the numbers, creates a `Map` with the counts, and then filters for those that fit the condition. Avoid the nested loops - even if you ensure not to run the inner one multiple times for numbers that you've already seen. (Also `prevNumbers` should have been a `Set`, so that you wouldn't need to loop to find but could simply lookup whether you've seen a number before).

Comment: Great! Thanks, so I'll try avoid nested loops in the  future, and check out Set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance is your concern, your code seems to be implementing O(n²)-time algorithm (due to nested `for..`-loops).

So, you may optimize that by doing the job in 2 passes (O(n)-time):

- to calculate the appearance of each digit, e.g. using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method and store the result into object where keys correspond to the digits themselves and values - to the number of appearances
- traverse above [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (using `.reduce()` again) to find out the maximum value passing described condition

I.e:

```js
const src =  [2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3],

      result = Object
        .entries(src.reduce((r,d) => (r[d]=(r[d]||0)+1,r), {}))
        .reduce((max,[key,val]) => key==val && val>max ? val : max, 0)
        
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: I'm amazed at how small your code is. Guess i'll have to study more to understand how this works, but i get the logic behind it, thanks!

Comment: @JavierAngelelli : You're most welcome. However, if ultiimate performance is your goal you may sacrify certain conciseness for CPU cycles, as `for(..`-loops may sometimes outperform high order methods. By the way,   your code has another issue (single equal sign rather than double within `if(...`-statement), I've found that while [benchmarking](https://jsbench.me/85k9ijzlij/1) your current solution compared to mine.

Comment: For me its not about ultimate performance, but just understanding what makes something perform. Now I understand a little bit more what to avoid if possible. Its good to know also that there are bencharking apps for the codes.

Answer (score 2):

In your solution, you have solved the problem using two for loops, which make your program's algorithmic complexity as `o(n^2)`. Instead, we can efficiently solve the problem using single loop, using linear complexity `o(n)`.

```
function exercise(a) {
  let hashMap = {};
  let maxCount = 0;


  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (hashMap[a[i]]) {
      hashMap[a[i]]++;
    } else {
      hashMap[a[i]] = 1;
    }
  }

  for (key in hashMap) {
    if (hashMap[key] > maxCount && hashMap[key] == parseInt(key)) {
      maxCount = hashMap[key];
    }
  }

  return maxCount;
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get why this one is getting upvoted - it doesn't bring any extra value to what I have already described in [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61459940/11299053). Moreover, the logic of solving original problem with a single pass is flawed (it returns `3` for `a=[1,2,2,3,3,3,3]`, whereas `2` is expected).

Comment: Thanks @YevgenGorbunkov, for mentioning it. I have updated the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Aman it makes it easier for me to understand the logic behind O(n2)